# Highcharts - Pie chart does not display slices

Tags: charts, highcharts, pie-chart

Odd one. I'm calling my pie chart, and when I do the grey background, data pipe connectors, and hover data with the numbers all show fine on the background. But no pie slices will show.

However, if I print out the chart, it shows the slices after I save the chart and go back to the page. Or, if I inspect element in Chrome, it will show the chart after I resize the inspector window. Almost like it's re-drawing the chart if I take any action, but not drawing it initially.

It works the same way in all browsers. No javascript errors are thrown.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'pie1',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'application usage'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +'';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#FFFFFF',
                            connectorColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b><br> '+ this.y +' ('+ Math.round(this.percentage) +'%)';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'percentage of application usage',
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Lessons', y: 25}, {name: 'Discussion', y: 65}, {name: 'Tests', y: 85}, {name: 'Dropbox', y: 92}, {name: 'Surveys', y: 105
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });

    </script>

    <div id='pie1' class='chart_container'></div>
```

Comment: I was using an older version of highcharts with a newer version of jquery. It's working now after matching up the right jquery with the right highcharts.